# Vertical vuetify tabs

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

I want to create vuetify vertical tabs, but I don't now props for it.

It's my vue template in component:

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-tabs color="grey" grow>
        <v-tab class="tabs-container-heroes"
               v-for="tab of tabs"
               :key="tab.id"
               :title=tab
        >
            {{tab.name}}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id">
            <HeroPresenter/>
        </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
</v-app>
```

Now I have tabs like this
[vuetify example](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#vertical-tabs

Vertical tabs are supported in `2.0` version on vuetify.

If you need vertical tabs on `1.5` version check this link https://gist.github.com/jacekkarczmarczyk/eca6015c176e85ea78706e63383bbe5c it may help.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for 1.5 version.